# What pattern is made by the satellites of ESA's Swarm Mission?

Tags: orbital-mechanics, artificial-satellite, propulsion, attitude, swarm

Swarm satellites, [like in this article](http://phys.org/news/2013-11-satellites-sardines.html), are satellites being released at the same time. Do they enter different orbits? If so, how do they power themselves to get into unique orbits?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

According to [eoPortal on ESA's Swarm constellation](https://directory.eoportal.org/web/eoportal/satellite-missions/s/swarm):

> The Swarm mission architecture is driven by the requirement for
>   separation of the various sources contributing to the Earth's magnetic
>   field. Hence, the space segment concept employs a three-minisatellite
>   constellation with the following characteristics:
>
> - Three spacecraft in two different orbital planes, with two satellites in a plane of 84.7º inclination and with one satellite in a
>     plane of 88º inclination
> - The two satellites in the 87.4º inclination orbit will fly at a mean altitude of 450 km, their east-west separation will be 1-1.5º,
>     and the maximum differential delay in orbit will be about 10 s.
> - The satellite in the higher inclination orbit (88º) will fly at a mean altitude of 530 km.
> - The spacecraft require some degree of active orbit maintenance to control the relative positions in the constellation (this is an
>     element of formation flight to support flight operations).
>
> [image]
>
> <sup>Overview of the Swarm orbit configuration (Quote and image source: [eoPortal on ESA's Swarm constellation](https://directory.eoportal.org/web/eoportal/satellite-missions/s/swarm))</sup>

The trio of spacecraft will use cold gas (N<sub>2</sub>) powered Orbit Control Subsystem (OCS) propulsion system, [magnetorquers](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Magnetorquer), and attitude sensing is provided by a star tracker assembly (3 star tracker heads), 3 magnetometers, and a CESS (Coarse Earth and Sun Sensor) assembly.